# AddClass doesn't work when ajax form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, validation

I'm trying to create a validation for my ajax form. I want to make a red border around the input when it's empty when you submit the form.

Unfortunately, `addClass()` doesn't work. The alert shows up, but that's all.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('.required').val() === '') {
      $('.required').addClass('error');
      alert("error");
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      url: 'php/php.php',
      data: new FormData(this),
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function() {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "success";
        document.getElementById("add").style.border = "2px solid green";
      },
      error: function() {
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "error";
        document.getElementById("add").style.border = "2px solid red";
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  border: solid 2px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="POST" action="php/php.php">
  Name:
  <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" class="required"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="Add" id="add">
</form>
```

I checked out some other posts, but still can't resolve the issue.

Edit: It seems that xampp had some problems importing external CSS files (or at least updating the data). The issue is resolved.

Comment: I edited your code in to a snippet where you can see that the class is added correctly, and the red border is visible. If it's not working for you then you need to debug further. I'd suggest ensuring that the `.error` class has high enough order of precedence to override any existing styles on the element. However, as it stands your demo code is working fine so I'm voting to close this question until you can provide accurate information to be able to debug it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It seems that it was a xampp bug, everything works fine.

Comment: I'd suggest deleting the question in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery UI?, because `addClass` is an async function in jquery ui and thus, `alert` statement in the next line is ran first which blocks the main thread.

Comment: When using jQueryUI `addClass('error')` will not be async. You need to provide the second parameter, duration, to make it async (see the [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/addClass/)). As the OP is not doing this, what you describe is not the problem.